# Cannot access Page without authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I deployed the sample application (the blue one you get when you create a new project) to IIS7 on Windows Server 2008. When I try to access mysite.com/home/about I get redirected to Accoun/Login.

This does not happen when I run the site on VS integrated server. 
I did not change any code in the project, so it sems to be an issue on the server.

IIS is set to integrated mode. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further on eu-ge-ne's answer, if 'Anonymous Authentication' is enabled then you need to make sure the user it is impersonating (default IUSR) has read access to your website directory.

If you have set it to use your application pool identity's user (default NETWORK SERVICE) then obviously make sure that that user has read access to your website directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled in the IIS/Authentication settings